# Extract and SUM numbers from a string

Tags: microsoft-excel, string

I have looked at the similar questions to this but could not find an exact solution to my problem. If there is a duplicate which can solve this I will close this question.

In cell A1 I could have a string, which will always consist of a number, comma, number etc.

There could be multiple numbers, always separated by a comma.

For example:

```
12,12,10,10
```

or

```
12,12,1
```

In cell B1, I would like to sum the numbers, so I would get a result of `44` or `25`.

How can I achieve this ?

The only thing I could think of trying was to use Text to Columns, but this kinda messes with the structure of the workbook as it requires more columns to be used. I was hoping for a formula I could just enter into B1 and drag down if possible.

Comment: Use simple user-defined function. Split your text value to string array by comma delemeter and calculate the sum of array elements converted to numbers.

Comment: @Akina I have no idea how to begin doing that lol

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I have no idea how to begin doing that

- Open your Excel file.
- Press Alt-F11, the VBA Editor window opens.
- Select Insert-Module in menu, new module windows opens.
- Insert the below code into the module window:

  ```
  Public Function ParseAndSum(source As String) As Integer
  Dim tmp() As String, i As Integer
  tmp = Split(source, ",")
  For i = LBound(tmp) To UBound(tmp)
      ParseAndSum = ParseAndSum + Val(tmp(i))
  Next i
  End Function
  ```
- Close VBA editor.
- Select destination cell (B1 for example).
- Press "function" knob (fx), Function Master window opens.
- Select "User-defined functions" category, select ParseAndSum function, click Next.
- Click source cell (A1), its address inserts into Source field.
- Click OK.

That's all.

PS. Do not forget to enable macros execution in Excel preferences.

Comment: Thank You ! I will try to learn from this how to begin creating UDFs for myself

Comment: @PeterH Remember - the function is available only in this file. To use it in another file you must do all the above in another file too.

Comment: I have now added this into a personal workbook and have this as add in I can use at any time; its that useful

Answer (score 2):

This can be done with a formula:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE(A1,",",REPT(" ",99)),(ROW($A$1:INDEX(A:A,LEN(A1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1,",",""))+1))-1)*99+1,99)))
```

This splits on the `,` and iterates the parts and sums them.

[image]

Comment: that is impressive

Answer (score 0):

Another way it can be done, and how it is traditionally answered, is to make use of a command from the "old" Excel 4 macro set.

You MUST use those commands in Named Ranges (or macros too, but usually people are seeking a non-macro solution).

There are two aspects to this solution. The first is just how to do the basics:

(Your data is in cell A1 and your result would be in cell B1, as asked for)

Set up a Named Range (maybe called "Result").
Give it the formula:

```
=EVALUATE(SUBSTITUTE(A1,",","+"))
```

Then use the Named Range in the formula in cell B1:  =Result

In the formula, SUBSTITUTE() is used "normally" to change out the commas for the plus signs that will be needed for EVALUATE() to work. EVALUATE() is the Excel 4 macro command and will do just that:  evaluate anything it can recognize as a formula (that's why the commas needed replaced).

The reason it must be used in a Named Range is a bit mysterious. They will not work directly typed into the spreadsheet's cells. They WILL work in actual macros. So the thought would be that Named Ranges must be regarded by Excel as a version (a "lite" version, to be sure) of macros with their work being done by the macro engine, not the sheet calculation engine.

Second aspect is how  to get the formula to refer to "the cell immediately to the left of the cell I want the result in"...

Select cell A2 and enter the formula as above. Enter the formula (copy and paste, type, however you like) and save it. Check the formula after the Named Range is established and make sure there is no "$" for the cell reference (you want "A1" NOT any version of "$A$1").

All set. Now, anywhere in your sheet, the "=Result" will refer to the cell to its immediate left. So copy it down the B column, or whatever might be useful, and it will work on the cell to its left's contents.

You DO have to get the second part right, but it's easy, eh?

Do a search for Excel 4 macro commands and you will find the entire manuall available, something like 600 pages of it, and there are some gems in there although some of those have been given to us in new functions over the years.