# Excel parse cell containing comma-space separated list and combine each value

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a multiple table set up in my workbook. Table1 is the Current State vs Table2 Optimized State.

Here is the example table 1 contains device 1 2 3 with average volumes of 500 each

[image]

Now for the optimized side, they will be combined into 1 device and I need the volumes of those devices to be summed up.

[image]

I need for Column CB2 to return a value of 1500.

I currently use VLookup for single value in a cell that don't have separated values by comma and it works as intended, everything else that is multiple values in 1 cell currently manually adding them up.

Comment: I asked a similar question that's got 3 very good answers that may be of use for you  https://superuser.com/questions/1371859/extract-and-sum-numbers-from-a-string

Answer (score 1):

Here is a slightly shorter formula than the one in the link in the comment:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(SUMIFS(AT:AT,G:G,FILTERXML("<a><b>"&SUBSTITUTE(BK2,",","</b><b>")&"</b></a>","//b")))
```

[image]

Comment: Awesome thanks! this is exactly what i was looking for. I am trying to figure out the functioning behind his formula as i will need some other functions for this going ward also. Can you advise what I should learn to configure this formula?

Comment: look into FilterXML and what it returns.